# Can't remove cookie

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cookies

I see that I remove the cookie in debug right after I use remove method of HttpContext.Request but when I redirect to another action I can still get cookie value. Why is that happening ?

```
public class LoginController : Controller
{

  public ActionResult Logout()
  {       
   HttpContext.Request.Cookies.Remove(Constants.User);     

   //I see that HttpContext.Request.Cookies[Constants.User] returns null in this line.

   return RedirectToAction("Login", "Login");
  }

  public ActionResult Login()
  {
    var userCookie = HttpContext.Request.Cookies[Constants.User];

    // But HttpContext.Request.Cookies[Constants.User] is not null here. I get the value from it.

    if (userCookie != null)
      return RedirectToAction(Constants.MainPage, Constants.MainPage);
    else
      return View();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove cookie you have to send it with an expiration date set to now or previous date. Removing it using `HttpContext.Request.Cookies.Remove(Constants.User);` just remove it from the collection, but it still exists in a client browser.

For example instead of using `Remove` function use:

```
    Response.Cookies[Constants.User].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
```